# Kubernetes PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound

Tags: kubernetes, docker-compose

I have a Kubernetes up and running on AWS working correctly.

I'm trying to deploy this [sample application](https://github.com/mikechernev/dockerised-php). I can run the project locally with `docker-compose up` without any issue

I used https://github.com/kubernetes-incubator/kompose to deploy it on Kubernetes. It worked but when I checked the pods I have the following error:

> [SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "web-claim0", which is unexpected., SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "web-claim0", which is unexpected., SchedulerPredicates failed due to PersistentVolumeClaim is not bound: "web-claim0", which is unexpected.]

I would like to share a volume between the 2 containers without setting up `aws-ebs`. Is it possible? I'd like to start with the simplest volume share as possible.

here is the volume configuration

---

```
Persistent Volume Claim     {5}

kind    :   PersistentVolumeClaim

apiVersion  :   v1

    metadata        {6}

name    :   web-claim1

namespace   :   default

selfLink    :   /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/web-claim1

uid :   a94c38da-de18-11e6-84b6-027fd28089d4

resourceVersion :   296178

creationTimestamp   :   2017-01-19T07:26:58Z

    spec        {2}

    accessModes     [1]

0   :   ReadWriteOnce

    resources       {1}

    requests        {1}

storage :   100Mi

    status      {1}

phase   :   Pending
```

Comment: Did you actually define the PersistenVolume itself in your cluster? If you do not want to use external volumes such as `aws-ebs` in the beginning, you could also share a host path directly on the worker node with your pod (but this will only work in single node setups, so it is only a viable option for the experimenting phase). See the [k8s persistent volumes guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/persistent-volumes/)

Comment: All this kubernetes configuration has been generated by Kompose from a docker-compose file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I was quite confused by how it works so it was difficult for anybody to answer. I'm just going to give a couple of hints.

1. Don't learn Kompose and just learn Kubernetes
2. The root cause of the problem was I didn't created the volumes on EBS first

Comment: But aren't stateful sets supposed to be able to do dynamic provisioning? If so, you shouldn't have to create the volumes first.